# Как реализовать перемещение окна без обрамления в Qt

Tags: c++, qt5

Вот пробный код:

Header

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include "ui_mainWidget.h"

#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QPoint>

#include <QDebug>

class FWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event);
    virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event);

private:
    Ui::FWindowClass ui;
    QPointF m_mousePoint;
};
```

Code

```
#include "FWindow.h"

FWindow::FWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Window);
}

void FWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        m_mousePoint = event->pos();
        event->accept();
    }
}

void FWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
}

void FWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    const QPointF delta = event->pos() - m_mousePoint;
    move(x() + delta.x(), y() + delta.y());

    event->accept();
}
```

Он конечно работает, но криво. 
Появляются вот такие ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В итоге сделал вот так:

```
void FWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    const QPointF delta = event->globalPos() - m_mousePoint;
    move(delta.toPoint());

    event->accept();
}
```

И все прекрасно заработало.